# What is the meaning of "Symbol Files" in WinDbg?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windbg, stack-trace, debug-symbols, cab

I have to understand my application's crashes from stack trace WPDEV. I followed up [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967782.aspx) but didn't understand Step 6 "Symbol File Path". What is that?

Thanks.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558829(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symbol files help you debug by (among other things) providing names for functions in call stacks rather than just byte offsets into a DLL.  Read [these pages of documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558823.aspx) to fully understand what a symbol file is and how helpful they can be while debugging.

The symbol file path is the local folder(s) on disk or remote symbol server URL(s) where the symbol files are retrieved from.  [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503) and [other organizations](http://www.symbolsource.org/Public) typically make available a symbol server where you can download the symbol files for any library they distribute.

Windbg and Visual Studio use this path and automatically figure out which symbols to download based on the libraries that are loaded in the process being debugged.  They are then (usually) cached locally to avoid downloading them repeatedly.